# Mock a class Autowired which has autowired class too

Tags: java, mocking, autowired

I'm doing a Junit test for my class. The source code of my class is this:

```
@Autowired
private LanguageRepository languageRepository;

@ApiOperation(value = "Languages", notes = "Get Languages.")
@CrossOrigin
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, path = Constants.REST_LANGUAGES)
public List<Language> getLanguages(HttpServletRequest request)
        throws GlobalException, ServiceException, SoapException, RepositoryException {
    LOG.info("Call Rest method: getLanguages");

    List<Language> languages = languageRepository.getAllLanguages();

    return languages;
}
```

the LanguageRepository has also an Autowired class called LanguageService.

the source code of the text is this:

```
@Mock
private LanguageRepository languageRepository;

@Before
public void initMocks() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void exampleTest() throws GlobalException, ServiceException, SoapException, RepositoryException {
    Language language = new Language("id", "name", "code");
    List<Language> languageListGiven = new ArrayList<Language>();
    languageListGiven.add(language);

    HttpServletRequest request = Mockito.mock(HttpServletRequest.class);

    Mockito.when(languageRepository.getAllLanguages()).thenReturn(languageListGiven);

    // 2- act
    LanguageController languageController = new LanguageController();
    List<Language> languageListReturned = languageController.getLanguages(request);

    // 3- assert
    Assert.assertEquals(languageListGiven, languageListReturned);
}
```

But when I call the method of the repository, I receive a nullPointerException.

It is posible to work with mocks for receive the object that I want in the testwhen I do the 'Mockito.when'?

Thanks!

Comment: Which line is the nullpointer on? Post the stacktrace in question.

Answer (score 0):

You have created a Mock for `LanguageRepository`, but you haven't injected it to the controller. You need to create a setter method for `languageRepository` in the controller and use it in test.

`LanguageController languageController = new LanguageController();
languageController.setLanguageRepository(languageRepository);`